# How can i have an if statement when creating an object in c#?

Tags: c#

I want something like this when creating an object,

```
            var modelObj = new TestModel
            {
                Id = id,
                Description = obj.Description,
                if (status == 1)
                {
                   Service = obj.Url,
                   Username = obj.ServiceUsername,
                }
                else
                {
                  Password = obj.Password,
                  Token = obj.Token,
                  FirstName = obj.FirstName
                }
            }
```

Is this possible to do with the if statement in c# ?

Comment: You can't. Add the conditional logic before creating any objects. Create different objects in the different branches.

Comment: You can use a ternary if to set some properties.

Comment: Overall this type of object creation clearly good candidate for Factory method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this afterwards if this is an object data assignment.

```
    var modelObj = new TestModel
    {
        Id = id,
        Description = obj.Description            
    }

    if (status == 1)
    {
       modelObj.Service = obj.Url,
       modelObj.Username = obj.ServiceUsername,
    }
    else
    {
      modelObj.Password = obj.Password,
      modelObj.Token = obj.Token,
      modelObj.FirstName = obj.FirstName
    }
```

Otherwise best bet is to use a class constructor instead of inline initialization.

Comment: This requires the properties to have a public setter. Object initialization only requires properties to have a public `init`. For example, `public string Id { get; init; }` versus `public string Id { get; set; }`. Using an `init` is better practice for encapsulation of the class.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this possible to do with the if statement in c# ?

You can do the same thing with expressions using the conditional operator.

```
    var modelObj = new TestModel
    {
        Id = id,
        Description = obj.Description,
        Service = status == 1 ? obj.Url : null,
        Username = status == 1 ? obj.ServiceUsername : null,
        Password = status != 1 ? obj.Password : null,
        Token = status != 1 ? obj.Token : null,
        FirstName = status != 1 ? obj.FirstName : null,

    };
```

Comment: Better to use the proper term: "expressions using the conditional operator" - it's important because you can't include a *statement* in an object initializer; everything has to be in terms of *expressions*.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for pointing that out Jon. I updated my answer with your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

If I suggest proper way to do it then.

Here in the question there is no information about type of obj. So I am putting that as markup Obj but that needs to replace with actual type.

1. Create method something like this.

```
    // Here you can use specific type instead of dynamic but your code miss that.
    public TestModel GetTestModel(int status, int id, Obj obj)
    {
        if (status == 1)
        {
            return new TestModel()
                {
                    Id = id,
                    Description = obj.Description,
                    Service = obj.Url,
                    Username = obj.ServiceUsername,
                };
        }
        else
        {
            return new TestModel()
                {
                    Id = id,
                    Description = obj.Description,
                    Password = obj.Password,
                    Token = obj.Token,
                    FirstName = obj.FirstName
                };
        }
    }
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any need to use `dynamic`. You have an excellent answer that was spoilt by this one inclusion.

Comment: @Enigmativity : you may be right. If you look at the question, person who asked the question does not provide anything around obj type so I have to make assumption.  You can read clearly in the comment I have provide above method.

Comment: I think it's a bad assumption. `dynamic` has very few situations were it is useful.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have updated answer as per your input. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of dotnetstep's answer (that's I'd be happy if he used, and then I'd delete this answer). I like it as it is really quite clean and easy to read.

```
public TestModel CreateTestModel(int status, int id, Obj obj) =>
    status == 1
    ? new TestModel()
    {
        Id = id,
        Description = obj.Description,
        Service = obj.Url,
        Username = obj.ServiceUsername,
    }
    : new TestModel()
    {
        Id = id,
        Description = obj.Description,
        Password = obj.Password,
        Token = obj.Token,
        FirstName = obj.FirstName
    };
```